# Unable to update composer.lock

Tags: silverstripe-4, composer-php

It shows error

**Problem 1**

> - The requested package silverstripe/cms (locked at 3.3.4, required as 4.3.*) is satisfiable by silverstripe/cms[3.3.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

**Problem 2**

> - The requested package silverstripe/framework (locked at 3.3.4, required as 4.3.*) is satisfiable by silverstripe/framework[3.3.4] but
>     these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

**Problem 3**

> - The requested package silverstripe/reports (locked at 3.3.4, required as 4.3.*) is satisfiable by silverstripe/reports[3.3.4] but
>     these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

**Problem 4**

> - The requested package silverstripe/siteconfig (locked at 3.3.4, required as 4.3.*) is satisfiable by silverstripe/siteconfig[3.3.4]
>     but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

**Problem 5**

> - Conclusion: don't install silverstripe/framework 4.3.0
>
>   - Conclusion: don't install silverstripe/framework 4.3.0-rc1
>   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v3.4.21
>   - Installation request for silverstripe/framework 4.3.* -> satisfiable by silverstripe/framework[4.3.0, 4.3.0-rc1, 4.3.x-dev].
>   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.14

here is my `composer.json`

```
{
"license": "proprietary",
"name": "silverstripe/installer",
"description": "The SilverStripe Framework Installer",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "silverstripe/cms": "4.3.*",
    "silverstripe/framework": "4.3.*",
    "silverstripe/reports": "4.3.*",
    "silverstripe/siteconfig": "4.3.*",
    "silverstripe-themes/simple": "3.1.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/PHPUnit": "~3.7@stable"
},
"extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
        "3.x-dev": "3.3.x-dev"
    }
},
"config": {
    "process-timeout": 600
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
```

}

and here is my composer.lock

```
{
"_readme": [
    "This file locks the dependencies of your project to a known state",
    "Read more about it at https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file",
    "This file is @generated automatically"
],
"content-hash": "ec3b880695b4cb0f347890bbac55f200",
"packages": [
    {
        "name": "composer/installers",
        "version": "v1.2.0",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/composer/installers.git",
            "reference": "d78064c68299743e0161004f2de3a0204e33b804"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/composer/installers/zipball/d78064c68299743e0161004f2de3a0204e33b804",
            "reference": "d78064c68299743e0161004f2de3a0204e33b804",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "require": {
            "composer-plugin-api": "^1.0"
        },
        "replace": {
            "roundcube/plugin-installer": "*",
            "shama/baton": "*"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "composer/composer": "1.0.*@dev",
            "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.*"
        },
        "type": "composer-plugin",
        "extra": {
            "class": "Composer\\Installers\\Plugin",
            "branch-alias": {
                "dev-master": "1.0-dev"
            }
        },
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "Composer\\Installers\\": "src/Composer/Installers"
            }
        },
        "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
        "license": [
            "MIT"
        ],
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "Kyle Robinson Young",
                "email": "kyle@dontkry.com",
                "homepage": "https://github.com/shama"
            }
        ],
        "description": "A multi-framework Composer library installer",
        "homepage": "https://composer.github.io/installers/",
        "keywords": [
            "Craft",
            "Dolibarr",
            "Hurad",
            "ImageCMS",
            "MODX Evo",
            "Mautic",
            "OXID",
            "Plentymarkets",
            "RadPHP",
            "SMF",
            "Thelia",
            "WolfCMS",
            "agl",
            "aimeos",
            "annotatecms",
            "attogram",
            "bitrix",
            "cakephp",
            "chef",
            "cockpit",
            "codeigniter",
            "concrete5",
            "croogo",
            "dokuwiki",
            "drupal",
            "elgg",
            "expressionengine",
            "fuelphp",
            "grav",
            "installer",
            "joomla",
            "kohana",
            "laravel",
            "lithium",
            "magento",
            "mako",
            "mediawiki",
            "modulework",
            "moodle",
            "phpbb",
            "piwik",
            "ppi",
            "puppet",
            "reindex",
            "roundcube",
            "shopware",
            "silverstripe",
            "symfony",
            "typo3",
            "wordpress",
            "yawik",
            "zend",
            "zikula"
        ],
        "time": "2016-08-13T20:53:52+00:00"
    },
    {
        "name": "silverstripe-themes/simple",
        "version": "3.1.0",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/silverstripe-themes/silverstripe-simple.git",
            "reference": "3cf638c170e649b6b122504c8f62d6d8946b853c"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/silverstripe-themes/silverstripe-simple/zipball/3cf638c170e649b6b122504c8f62d6d8946b853c",
            "reference": "3cf638c170e649b6b122504c8f62d6d8946b853c",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "require": {
            "composer/installers": "*",
            "silverstripe/framework": ">=3.0"
        },
        "type": "silverstripe-theme",
        "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
        "license": [
            "BSD-3-Clause"
        ],
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "Sara Tušar (Innovaif)",
                "homepage": "http://www.saratusar.com"
            }
        ],
        "description": "The SilverStripe simple theme (default SilverStripe 3 theme)",
        "keywords": [
            "silverstripe",
            "theme"
        ],
        "time": "2015-04-09T03:18:37+00:00"
    },
    {
        "name": "silverstripe/cms",
        "version": "3.3.4",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-cms.git",
            "reference": "f66e154a02e903d9f794cf693dec78eae2209951"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/silverstripe/silverstripe-cms/zipball/f66e154a02e903d9f794cf693dec78eae2209951",
            "reference": "f66e154a02e903d9f794cf693dec78eae2209951",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "require": {
            "composer/installers": "*",
            "php": ">=5.3.3",
            "silverstripe/framework": "~3.3",
            "silverstripe/reports": "~3.3",
            "silverstripe/siteconfig": "~3.3"
        },
        "type": "silverstripe-module",
        "autoload": {
            "classmap": [
                "tests/behat/"
            ]
        },
        "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
        "license": [
            "BSD-3-Clause"
        ],
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "SilverStripe",
                "homepage": "http://silverstripe.com"
            },
            {
                "name": "The SilverStripe Community",
                "homepage": "http://silverstripe.org"
            }
        ],
        "description": "The SilverStripe Content Management System",
        "homepage": "http://silverstripe.org",
        "keywords": [
            "cms",
            "silverstripe"
        ],
        "time": "2016-11-21T12:37:05+00:00"
    },
    {
        "name": "silverstripe/framework",
        "version": "3.3.4",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework.git",
            "reference": "be86c342b6f0c6f5cdb60c263bc95965ae3ee301"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/zipball/be86c342b6f0c6f5cdb60c263bc95965ae3ee301",
            "reference": "be86c342b6f0c6f5cdb60c263bc95965ae3ee301",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "require": {
            "composer/installers": "~1.0",
            "php": ">=5.3.3,<7"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "phpunit/phpunit": "~3.7"
        },
        "type": "silverstripe-module",
        "autoload": {
            "classmap": [
                "tests/behat/features/bootstrap"
            ]
        },
        "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
        "license": [
            "BSD-3-Clause"
        ],
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "SilverStripe",
                "homepage": "http://silverstripe.com"
            },
            {
                "name": "The SilverStripe Community",
                "homepage": "http://silverstripe.org"
            }
        ],
        "description": "The SilverStripe framework",
        "homepage": "http://silverstripe.org",
        "keywords": [
            "framework",
            "silverstripe"
        ],
        "time": "2016-11-22T13:12:14+00:00"
    },
    {
        "name": "silverstripe/reports",
        "version": "3.3.4",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-reports.git",
            "reference": "65e0b6ef35252beab36c5ea9066cb2e128a18e5c"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/silverstripe/silverstripe-reports/zipball/65e0b6ef35252beab36c5ea9066cb2e128a18e5c",
            "reference": "65e0b6ef35252beab36c5ea9066cb2e128a18e5c",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "require": {
            "php": ">=5.3.3,<7",
            "silverstripe/framework": "~3.3"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "phpunit/phpunit": "~3.7"
        },
        "type": "silverstripe-module",
        "extra": {
            "branch-alias": {
                "3.x-dev": "3.3.x-dev"
            }
        },
        "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
        "license": [
            "BSD-3-Clause"
        ],
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "SilverStripe",
                "homepage": "http://silverstripe.com"
            },
            {
                "name": "The SilverStripe Community",
                "homepage": "http://silverstripe.org"
            }
        ],
        "description": "Reports module for SilverStripe CMS",
        "homepage": "http://silverstripe.org",
        "keywords": [
            "cms",
            "reports",
            "silverstripe"
        ],
        "time": "2016-11-15T12:08:05+00:00"
    },
    {
        "name": "silverstripe/siteconfig",
        "version": "3.3.4",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-siteconfig.git",
            "reference": "031b0095db5676d5fad627c3f4237609fb61d39e"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/silverstripe/silverstripe-siteconfig/zipball/031b0095db5676d5fad627c3f4237609fb61d39e",
            "reference": "031b0095db5676d5fad627c3f4237609fb61d39e",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "require": {
            "silverstripe/framework": "*"
        },
        "type": "silverstripe-module",
        "extra": {
            "installer-name": "siteconfig",
            "branch-alias": {
                "3.x-dev": "3.3.x-dev"
            }
        },
        "autoload": {
            "classmap": [
                "tests/behat/"
            ]
        },
        "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "Will Rossiter",
                "email": "will@fullscreen.io"
            }
        ],
        "description": "Site wide settings administration.",
        "keywords": [
            "silverstripe",
            "siteconfig"
        ],
        "time": "2016-11-21T12:37:07+00:00"
    }
],
"packages-dev": [
    {
        "name": "phpunit/php-code-coverage",
        "version": "1.2.18",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage.git",
            "reference": "fe2466802556d3fe4e4d1d58ffd3ccfd0a19be0b"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/zipball/fe2466802556d3fe4e4d1d58ffd3ccfd0a19be0b",
            "reference": "fe2466802556d3fe4e4d1d58ffd3ccfd0a19be0b",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "require": {
            "php": ">=5.3.3",
            "phpunit/php-file-iterator": ">=1.3.0@stable",
            "phpunit/php-text-template": ">=1.2.0@stable",
            "phpunit/php-token-stream": ">=1.1.3,<1.3.0"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*@dev"
        },
        "suggest": {
            "ext-dom": "*",
            "ext-xdebug": ">=2.0.5"
        },
        "type": "library",
        "extra": {
            "branch-alias": {
                "dev-master": "1.2.x-dev"
            }
        },
        "autoload": {
            "classmap": [
                "PHP/"
            ]
        },
        "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
        "include-path": [
            ""
        ],
        "license": [
            "BSD-3-Clause"
        ],
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "Sebastian Bergmann",
                "email": "sb@sebastian-bergmann.de",
                "role": "lead"
            }
        ],
        "description": "Library that provides collection, processing, and rendering functionality for PHP code coverage information.",
        "homepage": "https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage",
        "keywords": [
            "coverage",
            "testing",
            "xunit"
        ],
        "time": "2014-09-02T10:13:14+00:00"
    },
    {
        "name": "phpunit/php-file-iterator",
        "version": "1.4.2",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-file-iterator.git",
            "reference": "3cc8f69b3028d0f96a9078e6295d86e9bf019be5"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sebastianbergmann/php-file-iterator/zipball/3cc8f69b3028d0f96a9078e6295d86e9bf019be5",
            "reference": "3cc8f69b3028d0f96a9078e6295d86e9bf019be5",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "require": {
            "php": ">=5.3.3"
        },
        "type": "library",
        "extra": {
            "branch-alias": {
                "dev-master": "1.4.x-dev"
            }
        },
        "autoload": {
            "classmap": [
                "src/"
            ]
        },
        "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
        "license": [
            "BSD-3-Clause"
        ],
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "Sebastian Bergmann",
                "email": "sb@sebastian-bergmann.de",
                "role": "lead"
            }
        ],
        "description": "FilterIterator implementation that filters files based on a list of suffixes.",
        "homepage": "https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-file-iterator/",
        "keywords": [
            "filesystem",
            "iterator"
        ],
        "time": "2016-10-03T07:40:28+00:00"
    },
    {
        "name": "phpunit/php-text-template",
        "version": "1.2.1",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-text-template.git",
            "reference": "31f8b717e51d9a2afca6c9f046f5d69fc27c8686"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sebastianbergmann/php-text-template/zipball/31f8b717e51d9a2afca6c9f046f5d69fc27c8686",
            "reference": "31f8b717e51d9a2afca6c9f046f5d69fc27c8686",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "require": {
            "php": ">=5.3.3"
        },
        "type": "library",
        "autoload": {
            "classmap": [
                "src/"
            ]
        },
        "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
        "license": [
            "BSD-3-Clause"
        ],
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "Sebastian Bergmann",
                "email": "sebastian@phpunit.de",
                "role": "lead"
            }
        ],
        "description": "Simple template engine.",
        "homepage": "https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-text-template/",
        "keywords": [
            "template"
        ],
        "time": "2015-06-21T13:50:34+00:00"
    },
    {
        "name": "phpunit/php-timer",
        "version": "1.0.8",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-timer.git",
            "reference": "38e9124049cf1a164f1e4537caf19c99bf1eb260"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sebastianbergmann/php-timer/zipball/38e9124049cf1a164f1e4537caf19c99bf1eb260",
            "reference": "38e9124049cf1a164f1e4537caf19c99bf1eb260",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "require": {
            "php": ">=5.3.3"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "phpunit/phpunit": "~4|~5"
        },
        "type": "library",
        "autoload": {
            "classmap": [
                "src/"
            ]
        },
        "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
        "license": [
            "BSD-3-Clause"
        ],
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "Sebastian Bergmann",
                "email": "sb@sebastian-bergmann.de",
                "role": "lead"
            }
        ],
        "description": "Utility class for timing",
        "homepage": "https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-timer/",
        "keywords": [
            "timer"
        ],
        "time": "2016-05-12T18:03:57+00:00"
    },
    {
        "name": "phpunit/php-token-stream",
        "version": "1.2.2",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-token-stream.git",
            "reference": "ad4e1e23ae01b483c16f600ff1bebec184588e32"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sebastianbergmann/php-token-stream/zipball/ad4e1e23ae01b483c16f600ff1bebec184588e32",
            "reference": "ad4e1e23ae01b483c16f600ff1bebec184588e32",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "require": {
            "ext-tokenizer": "*",
            "php": ">=5.3.3"
        },
        "type": "library",
        "extra": {
            "branch-alias": {
                "dev-master": "1.2-dev"
            }
        },
        "autoload": {
            "classmap": [
                "PHP/"
            ]
        },
        "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
        "include-path": [
            ""
        ],
        "license": [
            "BSD-3-Clause"
        ],
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "Sebastian Bergmann",
                "email": "sb@sebastian-bergmann.de",
                "role": "lead"
            }
        ],
        "description": "Wrapper around PHP's tokenizer extension.",
        "homepage": "https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-token-stream/",
        "keywords": [
            "tokenizer"
        ],
        "time": "2014-03-03T05:10:30+00:00"
    },
    {
        "name": "phpunit/phpunit",
        "version": "3.7.38",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit.git",
            "reference": "38709dc22d519a3d1be46849868aa2ddf822bcf6"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/zipball/38709dc22d519a3d1be46849868aa2ddf822bcf6",
            "reference": "38709dc22d519a3d1be46849868aa2ddf822bcf6",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "require": {
            "ext-ctype": "*",
            "ext-dom": "*",
            "ext-json": "*",
            "ext-pcre": "*",
            "ext-reflection": "*",
            "ext-spl": "*",
            "php": ">=5.3.3",
            "phpunit/php-code-coverage": "~1.2",
            "phpunit/php-file-iterator": "~1.3",
            "phpunit/php-text-template": "~1.1",
            "phpunit/php-timer": "~1.0",
            "phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects": "~1.2",
            "symfony/yaml": "~2.0"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "pear-pear.php.net/pear": "1.9.4"
        },
        "suggest": {
            "phpunit/php-invoker": "~1.1"
        },
        "bin": [
            "composer/bin/phpunit"
        ],
        "type": "library",
        "extra": {
            "branch-alias": {
                "dev-master": "3.7.x-dev"
            }
        },
        "autoload": {
            "classmap": [
                "PHPUnit/"
            ]
        },
        "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
        "include-path": [
            "",
            "../../symfony/yaml/"
        ],
        "license": [
            "BSD-3-Clause"
        ],
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "Sebastian Bergmann",
                "email": "sebastian@phpunit.de",
                "role": "lead"
            }
        ],
        "description": "The PHP Unit Testing framework.",
        "homepage": "http://www.phpunit.de/",
        "keywords": [
            "phpunit",
            "testing",
            "xunit"
        ],
        "time": "2014-10-17T09:04:17+00:00"
    },
    {
        "name": "phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects",
        "version": "1.2.3",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects.git",
            "reference": "5794e3c5c5ba0fb037b11d8151add2a07fa82875"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/zipball/5794e3c5c5ba0fb037b11d8151add2a07fa82875",
            "reference": "5794e3c5c5ba0fb037b11d8151add2a07fa82875",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "require": {
            "php": ">=5.3.3",
            "phpunit/php-text-template": ">=1.1.1@stable"
        },
        "suggest": {
            "ext-soap": "*"
        },
        "type": "library",
        "autoload": {
            "classmap": [
                "PHPUnit/"
            ]
        },
        "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
        "include-path": [
            ""
        ],
        "license": [
            "BSD-3-Clause"
        ],
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "Sebastian Bergmann",
                "email": "sb@sebastian-bergmann.de",
                "role": "lead"
            }
        ],
        "description": "Mock Object library for PHPUnit",
        "homepage": "https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/",
        "keywords": [
            "mock",
            "xunit"
        ],
        "time": "2013-01-13T10:24:48+00:00"
    },
    {
        "name": "symfony/yaml",
        "version": "v2.8.14",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/symfony/yaml.git",
            "reference": "befb26a3713c97af90d25dd12e75621ef14d91ff"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/yaml/zipball/befb26a3713c97af90d25dd12e75621ef14d91ff",
            "reference": "befb26a3713c97af90d25dd12e75621ef14d91ff",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "require": {
            "php": ">=5.3.9"
        },
        "type": "library",
        "extra": {
            "branch-alias": {
                "dev-master": "2.8-dev"
            }
        },
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "Symfony\\Component\\Yaml\\": ""
            },
            "exclude-from-classmap": [
                "/Tests/"
            ]
        },
        "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
        "license": [
            "MIT"
        ],
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "Fabien Potencier",
                "email": "fabien@symfony.com"
            },
            {
                "name": "Symfony Community",
                "homepage": "https://symfony.com/contributors"
            }
        ],
        "description": "Symfony Yaml Component",
        "homepage": "https://symfony.com",
        "time": "2016-11-14T16:15:57+00:00"
    }
],
"aliases": [],
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"stability-flags": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": 0
},
"prefer-stable": true,
"prefer-lowest": false,
"platform": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3"
},
"platform-dev": []
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to update the **composer.lock** only. Here is how I used to update composer.lock files without updating any code.

```
$ cd /path/to/your/project/
$ composer update nothing
```

You supposed to see output like below.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Hope it works for you.